# Determine which points maximize area of a polygon if chosen as vertices

Tags: algorithm, geometry, polygon

I have a polygon whose vertices are the center points of other 4 polygons. For these 4 polygons I also have the coordinates of their vertices. I would like to determine for each "corner polygon" the vertex that if chosen as vertex of the bigger polygon would maximize it's area. The polygon is a rectangle to which has been applied a perspective transformation, so I was thinking that it's a trapezoid.

[image: polygon]

I have tried calculating a rough center by summing the (x,y)s of the corners and diving by 4. I then chose each vertex based on the one that had farthest distance from this center point among it's peers. (something like `distance = (Xc - X)^2 + (Yc - Y)^2`, I avoided square rooting the result for performance purposes).

This unfortunately does not give the intended results. Usually just one vertex is substituted by the outer most "corner polygon" vertex, while the others are substituted by one of the other two "corner polygon" vertices excluding the nearest one.

What could be a way to create a better algorithm?

Comment: Described approach should give right result in most non-degenerate cases. Perhaps implementation mistakes lead to determination errors?

Comment: If you mean the vertex having the largest distance to the centroid among the four vertices of a corner polygon, this is certainly a poor choice, as the polygon can freely rotate without changing the selection and there is no influence of the other corners.

Answer (score 0):

A first approach is just by brute force: compare the areas of the 4^4 = 256 polygons obtained by combinations.

Slightly better, I guess that the vertices must belong to the convex hull of the point set (needs to be confirmed). Then discard the inner points and brute-force the remainig ones. As between one and three vertices of the corner quadrilaterals are on the convex hull, there are 3^4 = 81 combinations at worst (and a single at best; four in the given example; 2^4 = 16 is the most likely in practice).

[image]

You will need an efficient convex hull algorithm for the savings to be effective.

Answer (score 0):

The method I posted actually does work, as @MBo suggested there were implementation mistakes. To specify for future readers, this algorithm probably works only because the polygon is convex and/or a trapezoid, although that remains pure speculation based on the fact that my algorithm was produced heuristically.